# Why debuild and CMake are not including installed files into the package?

Tags: package-management, packaging, deb

Making a test package:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEBEMAIL="test@email.com"
export DEBFULLNAME="Test"

mkdir gbp-test-0.1

cat <<-EOM > gbp-test-0.1/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project(gbp-test)

install(FILES f.txt
    DESTINATION share
)
EOM

touch gbp-test-0.1/f.txt

tar -cvzf gbp-test_0.1.orig.tar.gz gbp-test-0.1

(cd gbp-test-0.1; echo m | dh_make)

sed -i -e 's/^\tdh .*/\tdh $@ --parallel --buildsystem=cmake/' gbp-test-0.1/debian/rules

(cd gbp-test-0.1; debuild -us -uc)
```

An the result is that CMake does the install step, but the file isn't in the final package.

(my previous version of this question wasn't specific enough, will take that one down soon)

Comment: Did you define a `debian/install` file of which lists what needs to be installed where on the system?  As well, does the package actually compile without issues (per the `debian/rules`)?

Comment: @Thomas W., `debian/install` is not required by the documentation (and why should I duplicate the install scripts?). Package compile. Of course, it complains about unimportant stuff.

Comment: Depends on the documentation you specify; the 'install' scripts that come with your software may not actually translate into being stored in the package correctly.  I tend to err on the side of caution and *always* specify a `debian/install` to make sure it knows what from the build goes where, which in turn helps populate the .deb files.  (note this page in teh Debian documentation, though, which suggests other methods as well - https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/modify.en.html#destdir.  We also don't have your makefile, so I can't comment if your install step is correct.)

Comment: @Thomas W., my example is complete. `dh buildsystem=cmake`part does the Makefile.

Comment: Why are the full contents of debian/rules not in your question?

Comment: @dobey, they are generated by `dh_make`.

Comment: So why is it a question on here and not a bug against dh_make? Sounds like this should be a bug report, not a question on here.

Comment: @dobey, added explanation to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the files are needed to be specified explicitly that because I've chosen a multi-package generation (`echo m | dh_make`). In single-package mode, install works by default.

Comment: This seems quite wrong. If your source package is configured to build a single binary package, then anything installed to the DESTDIR will be included in the package. If you have things missing from the package, then there is likely a problem with your CMakeLists.txt not installing them to the DESTDIR properly. You should not need to override dh_install.

Comment: @dobey, can you launch my script and see that CMakeLists.txt is okay? It's completely reproducible, there is no "if" about cmake.

Comment: With multiple packages, your answer is incorrect. You need to have install files for each package, to specify which files go in which package. All packages should not have all the same files, as this will create  file conflicts.

Comment: @dobey, having debian/install files is one of the options. The option that works for me is overriding the dh_install.

Comment: Then you need to correctly override dh_install to specify what files go in what packages. Installing all files in all packages is not a reasonable solution, to the problem which you created for yourself.

Comment: @dobey, now I think that the real problem is that I thought that I can't use wildcards in the debian/install files.

Comment: @dobey, fix ur votes, pls.

Comment: The problem was in the `debian/control` file, if you have more then one binary file declaration then you need add `debian/*.install` file for each binary packages. In the command above you were regenerating `debian/control` file from templates. It seems fixed in 16.04, `m` option for multi-packages removed from `dh_make`